# How to pass value to partial view or controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I am trying to pass an integer id from to a partial view; I am building comment system where use can comment on a post. Here is what I am doing

I am using **ASP.NET MVC Core**

Post.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.Models.Post
 @Html.Partial("ShowComments","Home", new MyApp.Models.Comment { PostId = Model.PostId})
```

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult ShowComments (int PostId)
{
  -- Get comment from database based on PostId
  return(comments)
}
```

Comment.cs

```
public class Comment
    {
      public int CommentId {get; set;}
      public int PostId {get; set;}

    }
```

ShowComments.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Comment>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @Model.CommentText
    }
```

Below is the error message I am getting

> cannot convert from 'MyApp.Models.Comment' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary'

I want to pass PostId from parent view to partial view, so that partial view can load the data for comments related to that post.

Comment: are you sure you are returning list of comments not one comment?
and based on your Comment class there is no `CommentText`

Comment: also on this like`@Model.CommentText` no need for the @

Comment: Your `ShowComments` model is declared as an `IEnumerable<Comment>`, but your partial include statement is only passing one `Comment`. Did you mean `@Html.Partial("ShowComments","Home", new[] { new MyApp.Models.Comment { PostId = Model.PostId} })` or do you need to update the type of your view's model?

Comment: @Amr Elgarhy thanks for your comments. For brevity, I didn't mentioned all class items. Comment class does have CommentText property

Comment: I will try with the modified partial view statement and will let you know. Actually, I want to pass PostId from main view to the partial view and want my partial view to take that Id and load comments.

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call a server method. In asp.net-mvc you would have use `@Html.Action()`. In core-mvc, you use ViewComponents. But I would suggest your view model just contains a property `IEnumerable<Comment>` so that you can render in in the view, or using `Html.Partial()`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial

Either you can use ViewComponent or have it comments as one of the property of main view's model and pass it into partial view like.

```
 @Html.Partial("ShowComments",Model.Comments)
```